# Proper way to handle error on ConfigFactory Load

Tags: scala, configuration, typesafe-config

I have my app selecting which conf file I want to load:

```
-Dconfig.file=src/main/resources/dev.conf
```

I created a Settings trait so I can easily extend Settings and have access to these variables across my app. In the implementation I am using ConfigFactory in the following manner:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load()
```

This is a problem. If that argument specifying 'dev.conf' is not present then this will look for 'application.conf' among others and the variables in 'dev.conf' will not be set. The app later explodes once it tries to fetch something not in conf.

How can I blow up immediently here once I know no configuration file has been set? That 'conf' value is not null/None and I dont have direct access to that 'dev.conf' argument that may have been passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `ConfigFactory.load()`,
 you can use

```
ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(pathToYourConfig))
```

This will ensure that a file from your -Dconfig options is being used, and is parsable.

To ensure that the config file contains all your required fields, you will have to have a sanity check. I like to instantiate a class which will assign all the config fields I need to a val, like

```
class Settings(conf: Config) {
      val projectName = conf.getString("projectName")
      val database = conf.getString("database")
}
```

Now on application boot, this class will throw an exception if the field is not present in the config file specified to `-Dconfig.file`

Comment: That first part defeats the purpose have having a -Dconfig as now I have to have a code change (changing the value of pathToYourConfig) everytime I want to switch from my dev.conf to staging.conf to prod.conf.

Comment: I agree on that sanity check - it might be the only way unfortunately

Comment: For the first part, you are supposed to get `pathToYourConfig` from the cli arguments, not hard code it.